# COUNTIF equivalent in Power BI / DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the below table and trying to move from excel to Power Bi. In excel I use `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$16,"<="&E2,$B$2:$B$16,">="&E2)` to get Count value but I wonder how can I calculate it in Power BI

```
open_date   close_date          Date        Count
16-Sep-18   14-Jan-19           16-Sep-18   1
21-Sep-18   19-Jan-19           17-Sep-18   1
23-Sep-18   21-Jan-19           18-Sep-18   1
17-Jan-19   27-Jan-19           19-Sep-18   1
26-Jan-19   28-Jan-19           20-Sep-18   1
27-Jan-19   28-Jan-19           21-Sep-18   2
19-Jan-19   19-Jan-19           22-Sep-18   2
19-Jan-19   29-Jan-19           23-Sep-18   3
27-Jan-19   29-Jan-19           24-Sep-18   3
20-Jan-19   30-Jan-19           25-Sep-18   3
23-Jan-19   30-Jan-19           26-Sep-18   3
26-Jan-19   30-Jan-19           27-Sep-18   3
28-Jan-19   30-Jan-19           28-Sep-18   3
21-Jan-19   31-Jan-19           29-Sep-18   3
25-Jan-19   31-Jan-19           30-Sep-18   3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, but they'll all use some sort of filtering.

Here are a couple examples:

```
CountIf =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Table1 ),
        Table1[open_date] <= MAX ( Table1[Date] ) &&
        Table1[close_date] >= MAX ( Table1[Date] )
    )
)
```

and

```
CountIf =
VAR CurrentDate =
    MAX ( Table1[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Table1[Date] ),
        ALL ( Table1 ),
        Table1[open_date] <= CurrentDate,
        Table1[close_date] >= CurrentDate
    )
```

Comment: thanks alexis, now added more colplexity. If open_date & close_date were in table1 and date & count in table 2?

Comment: If you use the second version, I don't think there would be much of a difference. You'd just replace `MAX(Table1[Date])` with `MAX(Table2[Date])`

Comment: Can someone please be kind enough to explain the process of execution of DAX from Alex's first solution above. I am not able to warp my head around it. TIA