# COUNTIF to check for distinct values in DAX

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax, powerpivot

I really need this formula in DAX but I really don't know how to build it:

```
= COUNTIF(<my_raing>,
     INDEX(<my_raing>,
         MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(<my_raing>), 0)
     )
  ) = COUNT(<my_raing>)
```

My real formula is this:

```
= COUNTIF(
    Table2[@[1]:[11]],
    INDEX(
        Table2[@[1]:[11]],
        MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(Table2[@[1]:[11]]), 0)
     )
  ) = COUNT(Table2[@[1]:[11]])
```

The range is 11 consecutive cells from only one row.
The example set of data is:

[image: Sample Data]

And the formula returns only `TRUE` or `FALSE` when all available (not blank) values are equal each other (it is enough to compare only one with all)

UnPivot data set seems like this:

[UnPivot Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPjY1.jpg)

Comment: Start by detailing exactly what your excel formula does, once you understand the logic then proceeding should not be too hard.

Comment: Hi Mike, you are right and I'm sorry. I edited the question and you can see what is the goal. Thanks!

Comment: May be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54442875/power-bi-countif/54443498#54443498

Comment: DAX doesn't work well with pivoted data tables. I strongly recommend unpivoting the `1` - `11` columns.

Comment: @AlexisOlson - only COUNTIF in not enough in my case.
And the set of data is huge and if I unpivot it will multiply it. OK if I do that then how can I implement my formula? :)

Comment: Yes. This is actually much easier in DAX once you [unpivot your table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098). If you post your data unpivoted, I'll explain.

Comment: @StanYan - it's good that you unpivoted the data. It'd be great if you could also post the unpivoted data example as text not image. It'd be also great if you include column names, make sure that data sample has cases for both TRUE and FALSE results, and clearly describe your desired outcome (for the data sample). Then, we can: quickly copy your data to Excel, write a formula, confirm that it does what you expect, and give you a correct answer.

Comment: Hey Alexis, I just added unpivot data example. It will be great if you help me.
Keep in mind that it is possible second column to start from 2 or other number and it is not sure that number are sequential. For example for "G" I can have only 2 and 4 in second column, for "K" I can have only 6, etc.

Comment: Hi @RADO, I can't add table, or I don't know how. But the set of data is simple. I update unpivoted set and now you can see most real example. For "B" I have FALSE. For All other it is TRUE because the values in columns "Z" are equal each other.

Comment: Friends, keep in mind that after all I need pivoted table and I can't use unpivoted date in my case! If it is not possible in DAX, just tell me and don't waste any more time.

Answer (score 0):

Not done in DAX but may be useful for other on here.

You can use this formula in column 12 (which I'm assuming is column L)
`=IF(MIN(A1:K1)=MAX(A1:K1), "TRUE", "FALSE")`

Comment: Hi @Marmiketi, actually I already have the perfect formula in Excel and your proposal is another way to find it. And then I need this formula in DAX :)