# Can we count TRUE() in DAX

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to count only TRUE() in this measure

Test = IF([Cumulative Month Sales] < 30000 && [Cumulative Month Sales] > 25000,TRUE(),0 )

IF is TRUE() and without table or column, can I count TRUE() in this measure
[image]

Please advise, Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [COUNTIF equivalent in Power BI / DAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54442875/countif-equivalent-in-power-bi-dax)

Comment: What is your data model? Can you post an image of the data model diagram? DAX code of the cumulative sales measure would be useful too.