# SUMIFS Reference but in BI

Tags: excel, powerbi

I would like to transfer a Excel sheet to BI to see if the execution time improves, but I'm have difficulties in replicating one of the formulas. I have a list of data and use the following formula:

=SUMIFS($B$2:B2,$A$2:A2,A2)

When I drag the formula, B2 and A2 stay the same:

=SUMIFS($B$2:B1,$A$2:A12,A12)

And here's an example of the sheet itself:

[image]

The formula in Excel does exactly what I need, but I couldn't replicate it in BI. Is it possible to do it?

Edit1: Adding a second image (answering a comment):
[image]

Comment: See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54442875) and links for `COUNTIFS`.

Comment: Ok, so I added a column "Step" to work as the "Date" of the example, because I want to sum everything that is equal or lower then the actual "Step" of each line. But that didn't solve the problem (I added a image to serve as an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost solved it yourself Daniel. The only issue you have is capturing the current row's value. Here's one way to do that:

```
Coluna = 
    var ThisStep = Plan1[Step]
    var ThisLocation = Plan1[Location]
return
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Plan1[Type of Change]),
        FILTER(ALL(Plan1), Plan1[Step] <= ThisStep && Plan1[Location] = ThisLocation)
    )
```

The result:

[image]