# COUNTIF in DAX for Power BI Card

Tags: powerbi, dax

Here is my sample table (for this report I'm using only one table, so there is no table-relationship-links to contend with):

| Cost Centre | Project | Invoice Approver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | AB | Person One |
| 123 | AB | Person Two |
| 123 | ZZ | Person One |
| 456 | TB | Person Three |

I have a measure already written `Approver = COUNT('Table'[Invoice Approver])`. In the sample above, `Approver = 4`.

I have created a new table showing *only* those combinations with 1 approver. The table shows 123|ZZ and 456|TB (NOTE: for this table, the approver(s) do not need to be shown, only the unique cost centre/project combinations).

My next step is to have a Card showing the net quantity of the filters: 2. But I need help in writing the DAX measure.

I have tried the following DAX formulae:

| Code | Result |
| --- | --- |
| `1InvApp = COUNTROWS(FILTER('Table',[Approver]="1"))` | "DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Integer with values of type Text." |
| `1InvApp = COUNTROWS(FILTER('Table',[Approver]=1))` | Blank (text) |
| `1InvApp = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'),[Approver]="1")` | "A function 'CALCULATE' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression." |
| `1InvApp = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'),[Approver]=1)` | "A function 'CALCULATE' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression." |
| `1InvApp = COUNTX('Table',[Approver]="1")` | "DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Integer with values of type Text." |
| `1InvApp = COUNTX('Table',[Approver]=1)` | "The function COUNTX cannot work with values of type Boolean." |
| `1InvApp = COUNTAX(FILTER('Table',[Approver]=1),'Table'[Approver])` | Blank (text) |
| `1InvApp = COUNTAX(FILTER('Table',[Approver]="1"),'Table'[Approver])` | "DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Integer with values of type Text." |
| `1InvApp = COUNTROWS(FILTER(ALL('Table'),[Approver]=1))` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54442875/countif-equivalent-in-power-bi-dax)) | Blank (text) |

**QUESTION:** What is the correct DAX syntax to show the desired total result, 2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the meaning of net quantity of filter equal to 2 or approver = 1?

Comment: My data has 4 lines. When I filter to only show combinations with a single invoice approver, there are 2 lines which show. My Card needs to show **2**.

Comment: You also ask about approver = 1. Are you taking this from the formulae? ```[Approver] = 1``` is my attempt to determine the quantity of invoice approvers for each combination of cost centre/project. the ```[Approver]``` measure is taken from ```COUNT('Table'[Invoice Approver])```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:
First:

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNT('Table'[Invoiced]), FILTER(ALL('Table'), SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Cost Centre]) = 'Table'[Cost Centre] && 'Table'[Project] = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Project])))
```

Secod:

```
OnlyOne = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(CALCULATETABLE('Table', FILTER('Table', var __xx = [Measure] return [Measure] = 1))))
```

[image]